# Why does the pdf file is successfully generated while the compilation ends with warnings in beamer using Kile?

Tags: beamer, kile

I don't know what is going with Kile when I use the document class beamer. The pdf can successfully be generated after the compilation but I get many error messages. Please here a minimal working environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 Presentation with beamer.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the following after the compilation:

```
[PDFLaTeX] example.tex=>example.pdf(pdflatex)
[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1
./example.tex:10:Font shape 'OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available (Font) size <5> substituted on input line 10...
[PDFLaTeX] 0errors, 2warnings, 0badboxes
```

I have already took the time to see in forums how so solve this problem but I didn't succeed! Any help would be more than appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble.

Comment: @PaulGaborit thank you! That's great! However, I get [PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1 but 0errors, 0warnings, 0badboxes

Comment: @PaulGaborit Furthermore in my real presentation I get an other error message, a strange one: Undefined control sequence \begin{document}!! Please not that the pdf is generated without any problem and this kind of messages do not show up in a documentclass other than beamer! Any help please?

Comment: the font message that you show is not an error it's just a message for information that you asked for a 4pt font but got a 5pt one but the error code being 1 is from the low level pdftex engine and does (or should) mean that you got a real error. That message isn't from pdftex it is from your editor, so either pdftex is generating an error or Kile is not correctly detecting the exit code. (I can't guess from here, and haven't use Kile)

Comment: You are misreading the error message which will not say `Undefined control sequence \begin{document}!! ` `\begin{document}` will be the location the error is detected, the undefined command will be shown on the line above

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for that. I got several errors: Rerun to get/PageLabels entry \n Not defining\perthousand \n Not defining\micro and also I get for all the includegraphics I used: Cannot determine size of graphics in file.pdf!!! I will become crazy. I don't know what is not going well with Kile?? Could you please suggest me any solution for that? thank you!

Comment: You need to make a small complete document that demonstrates the errors that you want help with, If you haven't defined micro and perthousand perhaps you want `\usepackage{textcomp}` but really you need to edit your question.